# How to configure Nginx so it will treat '?…' as part of the file name

Tags: nginx

Nginx is serving only static files, yet, some of file names contains '?'. Yes, the question mark.

All URLs that contains '?' yield 404 even though file actually exists. e.g.

```
> GET /foo?lang=ar.html HTTP/1.1
...
...
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

While a file named **foo?lang=ar.html** does exists in the expected location.

I wonder if there is a way to tell Nginx to treat the entire request as URL including what is currently translated as query string.

The only solution I have in mind is to write a small web server that does this and have nginx reverse proxy that web server, but I prefer get it done with nginx alone.

Comment: Well, a question mark is a special character that denotes the start of the query string, so it can never be part of the file name.. I can't test right now but maybe try replacing it in the URL with the escaped version, `%3f`.

Comment: @ShaneMadden That will work, but how would you be able to differentiate between a filename and just an URI pointing to a CGI accepting parameters? Looks like this is going to be an administrative nightmare. :) Edit: It will definetly work. Just tried it on my webserver and I got an `GET /header.php%3fbla HTTP/1.1" 404`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [try_files](http://nginx.org/r/try_files) with either `$request_uri` or `$uri$is_args$args` depending on whether you want to have the urlencoded bits decoded or not when looking for the filename.